# Glossary entries are not hyperlinked, but the index entries are

Tags: luatex, indexing, scrbook, hyperlink, glossaries-extra

I have two adjacent directives near the end of my `scrbook` document:

```
\printglossary[title={Glossary of Symbols}]
\printindex
```

After compiling with `lualatex`, the index entries are hyperlinked: upon clicking numbers, the pdf view jumps to the corresponding page.

[image: Index entries are hyperlinked]

However, the glossary entries are not: (nothing happens upon clicking the numbers.

[image: Glossary entries are not hyperlinked]

I'd like the glossary entries to be hyperlinked just like the index entries. Do you have any idea what might be the reason for the difference? More importantly, do you have any idea how I might fix this?

The preamble sets up the glossary thus:

```
\usepackage[automake,sort=use]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure out what the problem was: the `\usepackage{hyperref}` directive appeared in the preamble after the `\makeglossaries` directive. When I moved the `hyperref` directive before the `usepackage[...]{glossary-extra}` directive, the problem was fixed spontaneously, and the glossary entries became hyperlinks automatically.